# Matrix of common character features using vectors in R

Tags: r, string

I am using the R language.

I have about 9 vectors, each which is a character vector containing 4 to 3900 gene names. I basically want to look how many genes these vectors have in common. For example,

```
geneList1=c("gene1","gene2","gene6","gene28")
geneList2=c("gene2","gene4","gene1")
```

By using the %in% operator I can check how many features both vectors have in common:

```
geneList2 %in% geneList1
## [1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

Since I have relatively large vectors, ideally I would like to look at the proportion of genes in common, i.e.

```
mean(geneList2 %in% geneList1)
## [1] 0.6666667
```

Hence, it is relatively easy for two vectors, but how about 9 vectors? There must be a better way than comparing each vector with all other vectors. Ideally, I would like some 'features in common matrix', with 1's on the diagonal (each vector has all features in common with its own) and on the off-diagonal the features in common between different vectors. Something like:

```
          geneList1 geneList2
geneList1 1.0000000       0.5
geneList2 0.6666667       1.0
```

But for multiple vectors.

Comment: What language is this? SQL?

Comment: @Codor  This would be the R language.

Comment: `?crossprod` perhaps?

Comment: @docendodiscimus as far as I know, `crossprod`only allows matrix multiplication, and no intersect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest problem (as I see it) is that your vectors are not from the same length and thus you can't keep them in any other form rather a list. Thus, first step would be to get them from your global environment into a list object using `mget` and `ls` combination and then compare each against all

```
l <- mget(ls(pattern = "geneList\\d+"))
sapply(l, function(x) lapply(l, function(y) mean(y %in% x)))
#           geneList1 geneList2
# geneList1 1         0.5      
# geneList2 0.6666667 1
```

Answer (score 1):

There are possible many faster methods with the apply functions, but an old school nested for loop does the trick as well.

First make a list of all the separate genList, and loop twice over them.

```
genList1 <- as.character(sample(x = 1:10, size=1))
genList2 <- as.character(sample(x = 1:10, size=2))
genList3 <- as.character(sample(x = 1:10, size=3))
genList4 <- as.character(sample(x = 1:10, size=4))
genList5 <- as.character(sample(x = 1:10, size=10))
genList6 <- as.character(sample(x = 1:10, size=6))
genList7 <- as.character(sample(x = 1:10, size=7))
genList8 <- as.character(sample(x = 1:10, size=8))
genList9 <- as.character(sample(x = 1:10, size=1))

genlist <- list(genList1,geneList2,genList3,genList4,genList5,genList6,genList7,
                                    genList8,genList9)

N <- length(genelist)

commom_matrix <- matrix(0, ncol=N, nrow=N)
for(i in 1:length(genelist)){
    for(j in 1:length(genlist)){
         commom_matrix[i,j] <- mean(genlist[[i]] %in% genlist[[j]])
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, the method works as well if you have different sizes of vectors. No I don't know mget...

Comment: It is, but you have lots of syntax mistakes here, have to tested your code? `commom_matrix` != `common_matrix` and `genlist` != `genelist`

Comment: You didn't fix `genlist` and `genelist`